# Wpf mvvm Prism - separate shell for authentication window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have 2 modules in my Prism application, module for authentication(login/registration) and then main module. The app first displays authentication window and then on successful login it should activate main shell and close authentication. I want it to be separate because the windows are so different (no side menu, no toolbar, different height/width,..).

I tried solving with EventAggregator but when I switched back and forth, no views could be loaded.
Do I need to initialize the module everytime login is successful and logout button is clicked?

I have been stuck on this issue for some time now and can't think of an elegant solution,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need all the dynamic shell stuff? Or is it just overhead really? Most apps, dynamically composition isn't really a plus.

Comment: Im pretty new to prism and as far as i know thats how the app should be constructed. How would I solve this without using this dynamic shell stuff?

Comment: PRISM is a framework and you can use as much or as little as you like. When you read the docs it's hugely complicated with this shell thing and regions and all sorts of stuff. Some people pretty much just use delegatecommand and event aggregator.  TBH I find eventaggregator kind of clunky and I prefer mvvmlight and messenger. YMMV.